# Determining calling line without macro

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to determine the line number that calls a function without the aid of a macro?

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>

#define PrintLineWithMacro() \
  std::cout << "Line: " << __LINE__ << std::endl;   // Line 4

void PrintLine()
{
  std::cout << "Line: " << __LINE__ << std::endl;   // Line 8
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  PrintLine();           // Line 13
  PrintLineWithMacro();  // Line 14
  return 0;
}
```

which outputs the following:

```
Line: 8
Line: 14
```

I understand why each prints what they do. I am more interested if it's possible to mimic the macro function without using a macro.

Comment: The only way to get the line is with `__LINE__`; you have to use the preprocessor somewhere. (In other words, the preprocessor deals with raw *code*, and line numbers are part of raw *code*.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do the following:

```
#define PrintLine() PrintLine_(__LINE__)

void PrintLine_(int line) {
    std::cout << "Line: " << line << std::endl;
}
```

I know that this doesn't completely remove the preprocessor, but it does move most of the logic into an actual function.

Comment: This is a decent workaround, because you *have* to use a macro.  However, you should explicitly qualify the function call in the macro (::PrintLine_, or whichever namespace it's in) and use parentheses.

Answer (score 4):

C++ has caught up with this question in the c++20 standard.

In c++20 you may now do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <source_location>

void PrintLine(std::source_location location = std::source_location::current())
{
    std::cout << "Line: " << location.line() << std::endl;   // Line 8
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    PrintLine();           // Line: 11
    PrintLine();           // Line: 12
    return 0;
}
```

Another question is whether the compiler of your interest has caught up with the standard.
Note that the construct was present pre c++20 and you could try:

```
#include <experimental/source_location>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not portably.  On any given platform, you could basically re-implement the details of a debugger - the information is effectively stored on your stack as the return address.  You can get at that kind of thing with the backtrace() function on some platforms.